# Does not process values when passed to function from command line

Tags: php, command-line

### When I pass variable to function that i got from command line it returns invalid

```
    echo "Enter vendor name: [vendor1|vendor2|vendor3|vendor4|vendor5] : ";
    $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
    $vendor = fgets($handle);
    $tables = array();

    $err = validate_vendor($vendor, $tables);
    if(!$err) {
        exit("error: invalid vendor\n");
    }
```

In validate_vendor function I embeded the logic given bwlow that if vendor name is not among these vendor types then it return 0 otherwise 1. Even i press valid vendor name like "vendor1" then it also gives invalid vendor name and exit.

```
function validate_vendor($prev_vendor, &$tables) {
        if($prev_vendor == "vendor1")
        {
            ---
            ---
            
            return 1;
        }
        if($prev_vendor == "vendor2")
        {
            ---
            ---
            
            return 1;
        }
        if($prev_vendor == "vendor3")
        {
            ---
            ---
            
            return 1;
        }
        if($prev_vendor == "vendor4")
        {
            ---
            ---
            
            return 1;
        }
        if($prev_vendor == "vendor5")
        {
            ---
            ---
            
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  The first step would surely be to check the `$vendor` value you get from `stdin`, right?  Does it include the newline from when you hit return?  C'mon, make an effort, debug it! :-)

Comment: Okay thanx, I got solution after some research